# How can I intercept an HTTP 404 Response on file Upload when file size exceeds limit?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an MVC3 website that allows users to upload images.  If a user tries uploading an image that is greater than the allowed value in my web.config, they are given a 404 response.  I'm using a FileUpload control.  The user is getting 404 response when they submit the form and the file is too large.

Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/pscott/archive/2009/02/26/404-errors-with-fileupload-with-iis7.aspx) discussing how to fix the problem, but it only explains how to increase the max size of the file.  I don't want to increase the size, but rather give the user a friendly message when they do.

I'd like to intercept this response before it returns, so I can give them a friendly message explaining why they can't upload the file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Should that not be a 413 response?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is an exception being thrown that you can grab during the Application_Error event in the global.asax?

I'm not sure what this particular FileUpload control is that you mention, but with a plain MVC3 application, when I upload a file the Visual Studio web server ("cassini") responds with a 504 error.  The framework throws an HttpException when an uploaded file is too large. You could catch it like so:

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {
            var ex = Server.GetLastError();

            if (ex.Message == "Maximum request length exceeded.")
            {
                //respond another way.
            }
        }
```

This article is a good reference for the perils of large file uploads: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I tried that solution. My Application_Error() isn't getting hit. I'm getting this Exception HTTP Error 404.13. I'm assuming this is coming from IIS and not getting into my application. I tried throwing an exception from my Upload action and it didn't catch that either. My Global Filter works though for the exception I throw, so it displays the shared Error view.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer, it adds a response check before each response, but it does work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15532171/1033228

Plus you don't need to increase the size of your max upload size (further than your desired max) thereby opening yourself up to DOS attacks.