# Maximum Request Length Exceeded Not Redirect on Error Page

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, .net-2.0, maxrequestlength

I followed these links:

1. [Catching "Maximum request length exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)
   and
2. [ASP.NET - how to show a error page when uploading big file (Maximum request length exceeded)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126167/asp-net-how-to-show-a-error-page-when-uploading-big-file-maximum-request-lengt)

to display error page to handle uploading files exceeding the `maxRequestLength` in `web.config`

But my problem is, it is not redirected to the error page (the message says that the webpage cannot be displayed ). I do not know what I'm missing.

Here's my Code @ `Global.asax`:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    if (IsMaxRequestLengthExceeded(Server.GetLastError()))
    {
        this.Server.ClearError();
        this.Server.Transfer("~/Error.html");
    }
}

private bool IsMaxRequestLengthExceeded(Exception ex)
{
    Exception main;
    HttpUnhandledException unhandledEx = (HttpUnhandledException)ex;

    if (unhandledEx != null && unhandledEx.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
    {
        main = unhandledEx.InnerException;
    }
    else
    {
        main = unhandledEx;
    }

    HttpException httpException = (HttpException)main;
    if (httpException != null && httpException.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
    {
        if (httpException.StackTrace.Contains("GetEntireRawContent"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And @ `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.html" mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

It found out that when `maxRequestLength` was not initialized, it is set by default to 4MB. (I didn't set it because it is not important to me.)

Hope you could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't "Error.html" in web.config be same as in Global.asax "~/Error.html" ?

Comment: Hi, using `Error.html` causes error, i need the `~` character to specify the root path of the virtual directory.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "~/Error.html" in both places then (web.config also)?

Comment: I think not, my `web.config` is working as expected with `defaultRedirect="Error.html"` :(

Comment: My guess is that "Error.html" is not pointing to the error page and that is why it can't be displayed. Try using "~/Error.html" in web.config also. Check this: [ASP.NET paths](http://nathanaeljones.com/129/types-of-asp-net-paths/)

Comment: Hi, my `web.config` is working properly, just in the scenario above, when uploading files exceeding the `maxRequestLength`, it doesn't redirect to error page. Other than that, it displays the error page.

Comment: Hi, I am testing that, and i have the following error...
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' to type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'....-- somebody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" />
  <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="http://localhost:1899/ErrorUpload.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

just after

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

where you redirect to a Error Page...