# Redirect user to another page on Page_Error

Tags: asp.net, redirect, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum Request Length Exceeded Not Redirect on Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773346/maximum-request-length-exceeded-not-redirect-on-error-page)

I try to redirect user to some error page, when he uploads file that exceed maximum size.

I've put in Web.config following line to limit file to 10MB:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="360" />
```

On my page there's a simply form with standard ASP file upload control and submit button.
I've also defined redirection on Page level (I've tried also in Global.asax Application_Error handling, but results are the same):

```
protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Error is HttpException)
    {
        if ((HttpContext.Current.Error as HttpException).ErrorCode==-2147467259)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried also `Server.Transfer()` - not working.

When I try to upload file bigger than 10 MB I can debug and see that the code from `Page_Error` is being fully executed twice: even with `Server.ClearError()`, but the page is not redirected to `Error.aspx`. Instead, the standard, ugly "Connection has been reset" error page appears.

This code works OK if the error is another type, like division by 0 set on `Page_Load`. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here?

BTW. I use Visual Web Developer 2010 Express with .NET 4.0, WindowsXP. Testing on buld-in to VWD IIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**
OK, so the answer I've found is following: it can't be done via "normal" exception handling. Folowing code, found in one of mentioned link, put in global.asax, is some wokaround:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection runTime = (System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection)System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime");

    //Approx 100 Kb(for page content) size has been deducted because the maxRequestLength proprty is the page size, not only the file upload size
    int maxRequestLength = (runTime.MaxRequestLength - 100) * 1024;

    //This code is used to check the request length of the page and if the request length is greater than

    //MaxRequestLength then retrun to the same page with extra query string value action=exception

    HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
    if (context.Request.ContentLength > maxRequestLength)
    {
        IServiceProvider provider = (IServiceProvider)context;
        HttpWorkerRequest workerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));

        // Check if body contains data
        if (workerRequest.HasEntityBody())
        {
            // get the total body length
            int requestLength = workerRequest.GetTotalEntityBodyLength();

            // Get the initial bytes loaded
            int initialBytes = 0;

            if (workerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody() != null)
                initialBytes = workerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody().Length;

            if (!workerRequest.IsEntireEntityBodyIsPreloaded())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[512000];

                // Set the received bytes to initial bytes before start reading
                int receivedBytes = initialBytes;

                while (requestLength - receivedBytes >= initialBytes)
                {
                    // Read another set of bytes
                    initialBytes = workerRequest.ReadEntityBody(buffer, buffer.Length);

                    // Update the received bytes
                    receivedBytes += initialBytes;
                }
                initialBytes = workerRequest.ReadEntityBody(buffer, requestLength - receivedBytes);
            }
        }

        context.Server.ClearError();  //otherwise redirect will not work as expected
        // Redirect the user
        context.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try defining the generic error page in your web.config file, rather than handling it through code:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Path/to/myErrorPage.aspx" mode="On" />
```

You can also then define specific pages for each http status code, such as:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/error/generic.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/filenotfound.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error/server.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Here's a decent how-to article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355

**EDIT:** I've posted a suspected duplicate. Check it out in the comments of your question. It looks very similar to yours. Maybe asp.net has a problem handling these types of errors..

**EDIT 2:** also - I believe the error you're trying to handle is [http 413](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.14):

```
<error statusCode="413" redirect="/error/upload.aspx"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I've tried also that, and it's not changing anything with my problem...